# PyQt5 show fullscreen dialog

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5

I would like my dialog be fullscreen. I use that code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = QDialog()
dialog.showFullScreen()
app.exec()
```

But dialog keeps its normal state. My platform is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Tested on qt4. Same problem

Comment: Works fine on archlinux - must be an ubuntu problem.

Comment: @ekhumoro which exact version of pyqt5 do you use?

Comment: Currently qt-5.11.0 / pyqt-5.10.1 and qt-4.8.7 / pyqt-4.12.1, but it  also works fine with e.g. qt-5.6 / pyqt-5.6.

Comment: @ekhumoro same pyqt for me but qt is 5.5.1/4.4.8. Maybe here is the problem

Comment: @ekhumoro have you heard about this problem? Maybe there is a workaround for it?

Comment: Well, why not try upgrading to at least qt-5.6? Although, if it works (for me) with qt4/pyqt4, I don't see why this should make a difference. It still looks like an ubuntu issue to me.

Comment: @ekhumoro yes, I'll try to update, but I'm looking for solution which would work "as is" without force updates. And 5.5.1 is the last version in ubuntu repos, I don't want install updates on all machines

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @ekhumoro hint, it is strange Ubuntu bug. The solution is:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = QDialog()
dialog.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.WindowType_Mask)
dialog.showFullScreen()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Where did you discover this work-around? Is there a bug report somewhere?

Comment: Here is someone faced the same problem on Ubuntu: http://www.cyberforum.ru/qt/thread1442644.html